# add wordpress header to external page

Tags: wordpress

My website is searchcraigs.com
I am trying to add my wordpress header to an external (single home page) on my website. I followed the instruction at this url:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Now I can get other wordpress code working on that page but I need it to show the exact same header that is listed here: 
http://searchcraigs.com/blog/

What am I missing? I can I make my wordpress header show on my home page on not only in the blog section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not as trivial as integrating the internal bootstrap file. You'd have to fetch the current template's `header.php` file - not sure whether that is feasible at all.

Have you considered doing it the other way round - having a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) in your theme, and including the external page in *that?*

Comment: That might work but unfortunately I'm not that code savvy. Hmmm... no easy way to do what I'm trying to do??